# How to make ConstrainedBox constrained by its parent in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, constraints, overflow, constrainedbox

I'm using a TextScroll() inside a ConstrainedBox, but it sometimes overflows beyond the screen limits and I want it to not do that. How can I make the ConstrainedBox constrained by its parent or how do I avoid the screen overflow?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop overflow you can wrap the text with a flexible widget and/or add `overflow : Overflow.elipsis` to the text widget